# Different Parametrized arguments for different Tests JUNIT

Tags: java, junit

Okay so I'm building Test Cases for my project and I'm Using JUnit for testing. Now the problem I'm facing is that I need different set of arguments for different test cases of the same file.

```
public class ForTesting{
    //Test 1 should run on ips {1, true} and {2,true}
    @Test
    public void Test1()
    {
        //Do first Test case
    }
    //Test 2 should run on ips {3,true} and {4,true}
    @Test
    public void Test2()
    {
        //Do another Test case
    }
}
```

I know I can provide multiple arguments using parametrized arguments but the problem is the same set of arguments run for all the test cases.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not looking ONLY for *standard junit parametrized* tests, and depending on your company's legal policies you can use (at least) the following 2 libraries, which make things easier (both to implement and read):

**1) [JUnitParams](https://github.com/Pragmatists/junitparams) (Apache 2)**

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class PersonTest {

  @Test
  @Parameters({"17, false", 
               "22, true" })
  public void shouldDecideAdulthood(int age, boolean expectedAdulthood) throws Exception {
    assertThat(new Person(age).isAdult(), is(expectedAdulthood));
  }
}
```

**2) [Zohhak](https://github.com/piotrturski/zohhak) (LGPL)** inspired by JUnit params but bringing some [more sugar](https://github.com/piotrturski/zohhak/blob/master/Full-Guide.md) to the table (easy separator config, converters, etc)

```
@RunWith(ZohhakRunner.class)
public class PersonTest {

  @TestWith({"17, false", 
             "22, true" })
  public void shouldDecideAdulthood(int age, boolean expectedAdulthood) throws Exception {
    assertThat(new Person(age).isAdult(), is(expectedAdulthood));
  }
}
```

---

Credits: Examples above have been *shamelessly* copied and adjusted from JUnitParams' readme.

Comment: Thanks thats what i needed!

Comment: @moldovean not yet, just read about it a while ago, but did not have the context for it so far

Answer (score 1):

Few options:

Use [Theories](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/experimental/theories/Theories.html).

In a @Theory, use [Assume.assumeThat](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html).

```
@Theory
public void shouldPassForSomeInts(int param) {
     Assume.assumeTrue(param == 1 || param == 2);
}

@Theory
public void shouldPassForSomeInts(int param) {
     ...
}
```

Or use [@TestedOn](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/experimental/theories/suppliers/TestedOn.html).

```
@Theory
public void shouldPassForSomeInts(@TestedOn(ints={1, 2}) int param) {
     ...
}

@Theory
public void shouldPassForSomeInts(@TestedOn(ints={3,4}) int param) {
     ...
}
```